# created hook for vuex / nuxtClientInit?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I was wondering whats the best way to do something like `nuxtClientInit`. I'm trying to load the Auth State as early as possible on the client and save it in my vuex store but not on the server side. It would be great if vuex had something like the `created` hook for components but that doesn't exist to my knowledge.

How could I achieve this behavior? One way could be calling an action from a layout but is that the best way?

Comment: you can add this into the main `App.vue` `created` method, or the base component to that

Comment: @DerekPollard There is no App.vue in nuxt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand the nuxt team are working on a nuxtClientInit feature but before they release that you could just make your own. To understand the workflow that nuxt undertakes when there is a request you can look at the lifecycle [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#schema). This shows that nuxtServerInit is called first then middleware. During this middleware call nuxt.config.js is served and this contains your custom configuration. Part of this is 'plugins' which as the docs say,

> This option lets you define JavaScript plugins that should be run
>   before instantiating the root Vue.js application.

So if you write a plugin to call a store action you can then get and set your local storage from there. So, start with a nuxt-client-init plugin:

```
//nuxt-client-init.client.js
export default async context => {
  await context.store.dispatch('nuxtClientInit', context)
}
```

then add the plugin to nuxt.config.js:

```
//nuxt.config.js
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/nuxt-client-init.client.js'
  ],
```

If you notice the naming convention here, the .client.js part of the plugin tells nuxt this is a client only plugin and is shorthand for `'{ src: '~/plugins/nuxt-client-init.js', mode: 'client' }'` which since nuxt 2.4 is the way to define the old `'{ src: '~/plugins/nuxt-client-init.js', ssr: false }'`. Anyway, you now have a call to your store so you can have an action to call from local storage and set a state item.

```
//store/index.js
export const actions = {
  nuxtClientInit({ commit }, { req }) {
    const autho = localStorage.getItem('auth._token.local') //or whatever yours is called
    commit('SET_AUTHO', autho)
    console.log('From nuxtClientInit - '+autho)
  }
}
```

You probably need to restart your app for that to all take effect but you are then getting and using your Auth State without any of that pesky nuxtServerInit business.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the best solution!